# Is there a method like '__getattribute__' for class (not instance) variables?

Tags: python

I have a class `sysprops` in which I'd like to have a number of constants.  However, I'd like to pull the values for those constants from the database, so I'd like some sort of hook any time one of these class constants are accessed (something like the **getattribute** method for instance variables).

```
class sysprops(object):
    SOME_CONSTANT = 'SOME_VALUE'

sysprops.SOME_CONSTANT  # this statement would not return 'SOME_VALUE' but instead a dynamic value pulled from the database.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other two answers have a valid method. I like to take the route of 'least-magic'.

You can do something similar to the metaclass approach without actually using them. Simply by using a decorator.

```
def instancer(cls):
    return cls()

@instancer
class SysProps(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        return key # dummy
```

This will create an instance of `SysProps` and then assign it back to the `SysProps` name. Effectively shadowing the actual class definition and allowing a constant instance.

Since decorators are more common in Python I find this way easier to grasp for other people that have to read your code.

Comment: It should be noted that this makes it impossible to instantiate the `SysProps` class. Instead of using this method I would actually opt for simply doing `SysProps = SysProps()` instead, seems clearer to me :)

Comment: You may not always want a user to instantiate a class--Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Although I think it is a *very* bad idea to do this, it is possible:

```
class GetAttributeMetaClass(type):
    def __getattribute__(self, key):
        print 'Getting attribute', key

class sysprops(object):
    __metaclass__ = GetAttributeMetaClass
```

Comment: I think this is the perfect answer. Why do you think it's *very* bad idea? Is it because of the taboo around the metaclass

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim In general it's better to define properties explicit than implicit. Where a metaclass already allows for some "magic" by dynamically adding methods/properties to classes, making the metaclass itself magic makes it even harder to trace how/why code works.

Answer (score 0):

`sysprops.SOME_CONSTANT` can be the return value of a function if `SOME_CONSTANT` were a property defined on `type(sysprops)`.

In other words, what you are talking about is commonly done if `sysprops` were an instance instead of a class.

But here is the kicker -- *classes are instances of  metaclasses*. So everything you know about controlling the behavior of instances through the use of classes applies equally well to controlling the behavior of classes through the use of metaclasses.

Usually the metaclass is `type`, but you are free to define other metaclasses by subclassing `type`. If you place a property `SOME_CONSTANT` in the metaclass, then the instance of that metaclass, e.g. `sysprops` will have the desired behavior when Python evaluates `sysprops.SOME_CONSTANT`.

---

```
class MetaSysProps(type):
    @property
    def SOME_CONSTANT(cls):
        return 'SOME_VALUE'

class SysProps(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaSysProps


print(SysProps.SOME_CONSTANT)
```

yields

```
SOME_VALUE
```